# Window.Print makes page background with opacity turn to white

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, windows

I have asp.Net webpage with some controls on it like the textbox , radiobuttons etc.
This page is the Print Page. So by default when this page is opened the javascript on the page does a window.print which then displays a list of printers.

Before the window.print command is executed i have a div with a css class applied

```
.modalBackgroundQ
{
    background-color: White;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0.2;
}
```

this div is spread out across the entire page covering all of the controls basically making all of its controls not editable.

Now, the problem here is once the print window is displayed with list of printers and the user does a Cancel of the print window. Then the window covering the div goes blank as in switches to white color basically hidding all the controls on the page under the div

i am using a Windows 7 with IE 8 installed on it ?

Any suggestions as to what could be the probelem ?

Comment: You could try setting the z-index of the CSS div class.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css" media="print"></style>
```